# Vuetify Datatable Actions Row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Is it possible to left align the **rows per pages** and **page navigation** and put a button in its place in the same row?

[image]

Comment: You want the button at the left or right? The picture shows it at left but from your explanation, it seems you want it at right

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to show the idea of what I was looking for. I figured I could figure out the alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actions row are aligned right by default. There is a way to achieve what you want though. You can use **custom pagination** and hide the current one:

```
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
    hide-actions
    :pagination.sync="pagination"
  >
```

And add this after the datatable:

```
<v-layout row justify-center>
    <v-pagination v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages"></v-pagination>
    <v-btn class="test">test</v-btn>
</v-layout>
```

See more [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables).

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/eXQXPJ) in action.

Comment: It is possible to still use vuetify style pagination elements? or would I have to recreate them to look similar?

Comment: You can change the icons by using `prev-icon` and `next-icon` and their color. See more [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations)

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way is to add the button to some data table slot you use and just position the button relatively to the table.

```
<v-data-table
    style="position: relative;">

    <template slot="footer">
        <v-btn style="position: absolute; left: 10px; bottom: 10px;">
            test
        </v-btn>
    </template>

</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way by CSS :

template in your datatable :

```
<template v-slot:actions-prepend>
    <v-btn>
        Click me !
    </v-btn>
</template>
```

CSS :

```
.my-grid .v-datatable__actions > div:first-child {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Working snippet :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick() { this.dark = !this.dark; }
  },
  data: {
    dark: true,
    headers: [{
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        value: 'name'
      },
      {
        text: 'Calories',
        value: 'calories'
      },
      {
        text: 'Fat (g)',
        value: 'fat'
      },
      {
        text: 'Carbs (g)',
        value: 'carbs'
      },
      {
        text: 'Protein (g)',
        value: 'protein'
      },
      {
        text: 'Iron (%)',
        value: 'iron'
      }
    ],
    desserts: [{
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.my-grid .v-datatable__actions > div:first-child {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app :dark="dark">
    <v-content>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="my-grid">
        <template v-slot:items="{item}">
            <tr>
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{item.calories}}</td>
              <td>{{item.fat}}</td>
              <td>{{item.carbs}}</td>
              <td>{{item.protein}}</td>
              <td>{{item.iron}}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        <template v-slot:actions-prepend>
              <v-btn @click="onClick">
                  Switch mode
              </v-btn>
          </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Vuetify did you use for this? I don't see a slot for `actions-prepend` in the most recent docs.

Comment: @totalhack it works only for previous versions, not sure for actuals, see in the snippet join for the exact version